# A runall command in setup.py

Tags: python, python-3.x, design-patterns, setuptools

I have created many custom commands by extending the command class in `setuptools` python library. The commands are like Clean, RunTest (each individual class with their `run(self)` method). 
I have now created a RunAll Class which if also sub classing the `Command` class and needs to call other commands. Let me show some of my code so as to make it more clear.

```
class Clean(Command):

description = 'Cleans the build'
user_options = []

def initialize_options(self):
    pass

def finalize_options(self):
    pass

def clean(self):
    print("Cleaning")

def run(self):
    self.clean()
```

There are some more classes like these like Runtests etc. which are of similar format.
Now I create a class called as RunAll which runs all these commands (trying to simulate `ant all` command). So the code is like.

```
class RunAll(Command):
"""
runs few specific commands mentioned
"""

description = 'Runs specific commands mentioned'
user_options = []

def initialize_options(self):
    pass

def finalize_options(self):
    pass

def run(self):
    # init,clean,version,build,test,dist
    Clean().clean()
    Version().printVersion()
    RunTests().runtests()
    Dist().dist()
```

Now when I run `python setup.py runall` I get the following error.

```
  File "C:\Users\rsareen\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\setuptools\__init__.py", line 129, in setup
return distutils.core.setup(**attrs)
  File "C:\Users\rsareen\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\distutils\core.py", line 148, in setup
dist.run_commands()
  File "C:\Users\rsareen\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\distutils\dist.py", line 955, in run_commands
self.run_command(cmd)
  File "C:\Users\rsareen\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\distutils\dist.py", line 974, in run_command
cmd_obj.run()
  File ".\setup.py", line 58, in run
Clean().clean()
TypeError: __init__() missing 1 required positional argument: 'dist'
```

Its not able to get the `dist` parameter in the `Command` class.

Basically i am not able to instantiate the commands.
But when i do `python setup.py clean`, it runs perfectly.

Is setuptools designed this way and I need to change my design, or there is any other way to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Command classes seems to [require](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/ef158c3ced3fce39e43f54e8d149dc2714e3456e/Lib/distutils/cmd.py#L47) a parameter and store that parameter in [`self.distribution`](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/ef158c3ced3fce39e43f54e8d149dc2714e3456e/Lib/distutils/cmd.py#L61). So pass it to command classes you create:

```
Clean(self.distribution).clean()
…
```

Or you can run a different command by name using [`run_command`](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/ef158c3ced3fce39e43f54e8d149dc2714e3456e/Lib/distutils/cmd.py#L308):

```
self.run_command('clean')
…
```